# How to add header to request and response for json in datapower

Tags: json, request-headers, ibm-datapower

Here my requirement is to add headers to Json message that is input to datapower and i need to remove header of the json message which is coming from backend server.Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We are here to help you solve your issues. Rather then completely answering and writing code for you. Please let us us know what efforts have you put to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Add Headers :

use 
"dp:set-http-request-header name="'Accept'" value="'application/json'" />"
or
You can inject Headers using UserAgent in XmlManager.

Remove Headers:
"dp:remove-http-request-header name="Header Name"/>"